# Issues with multiple image uploads PaperClip, Nested Form Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I've gone through a few questions (primarily [14880100](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880100/multiple-upload-with-paperclip-in-ror?lq=1) & [2308103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308103/ror-step-by-step-multiple-images-using-paperclip?rq=1)) and haven't been able to figure out how to upload multiple images to my Rails Model.

Here is my code:

**photo.rb**

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :location_id, :name, :picture
belongs_to :location
has_attached_file :picture,
                styles: { large: "", medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#" },
                storage: :s3,
                :s3_protocol => :https,
                url: ":s3_domain_url",
                default_url: "placeholder.jpg",
                path: "/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename",
                s3_region: ENV["S3_REGION"],
                s3_credentials: Proc.new { |a| a.instance.s3_credentials }




def s3_credentials
{
  bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
  access_key_id: ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
}
 end
end
```

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode
  acts_as_votable
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
  has_many :photos
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy


end
```

**routes.rb**

```
 resources :locations do
  resources :photos
  resources :comments
    member do
      put "like" => "locations#upvote"
      put "dislike" => "locations#downvote"
    end
 end
```

**/views/locations._form.html.erb**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-md-5">
  <%= nested_form_for @location, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%# all your building fields .... %>

  <%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
    <% if photo.object.new_record? %>
      <%= photo.file_field(:picture) %>
    <% else %>
      <%= image_tag(photo.url(:thumb)) %>
      <%= photo.hidden_field :_destroy %>
      <%= photo.link_to_remove "X" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add photo", :photos %></p>

<% end %></div>
```

**/views/locations.show.html.erb**

```
<%= image_tag @location.photos.picture.url %>
```

The error I've been receiving is "undefined method `picture'".

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: in `photos ` collection you will receive array of active relation object you have iterate over photos

Answer (score 1):

The code `@location.photos` will return an array, you must iterate over it, Here is the code:

```
<% @location.photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag(photo.picture.url)%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just tried using this code and received the following error: 'SQLite3::SQLException: no such column photos.location_id: SELECT "photos".* FROM "photos" WHERE "photos"."location_id" = ?'    - I checked my schema, and picture was added as a string.

Comment: @pjh_1222 That means you don't have a `location_id` column in `photos` table.You should add to resolve the error.

Comment: @pjh_1222 location_id is the default foreign key between locations and photos tables.  I just read the paperclip doc,  you can show the image by this:   <%= image_tag(photo.picture(:medium))%>.

Comment: @Pavan thank you for the help. I added that column in photos, no more error. However, none of the images I uploaded when creating the location appear in the show page.